# Gateway timeout error when opening JupyterLab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-dataproc

i have a cluster in Google Cloud with a static IP set up. This has been working fine more than a year. Recently I noticed that when I start the cluster and try to open JupyterLabs I get a *gateway timeout error* or "*This page isn't working ...dataproc.googleusercontent.com is currently unable to handle this request*".

I have scheduled jobs running on this cluster and they run just fine. I have other clusters and when I open those up it's also fine.

I just thinking is there any other fix I could try than just redoing the cluster.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any error code ex: 500,504..etc?